# Mongodb atlas serverless index cost

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, amazon-dynamodb, mongodb-atlas

I would like some clarifications on the cost of writing to a mongodb serverless (Atlas) in a collection with indexes.
In dynamodb when you create an index (local secondary index) and write an item in the table that is supposed to consume 1 WCU you are charged 2 WCU if you use an index because dynamodb has to keep up to date the index table (you are even charged 3 WCU for an update).

I would like to know if it is the same for mongodb serverless, I'm not sure to understand their documentation. When you have a collection with 1 or more indexes and you write at it are you charge 1 WCU for the whole operation or do they charge you more when you use indexes?
(let's suppose that the whole operations do not exceed 1 WCU maximum size).

From the mongodb serverless site:
[image]

Comment: They specify that you pay for index reads also, so in an update if that update utilizes an index you will pay for the read portion as well.